# Reset disabled input field's value

Tags: meteor

HTML:

```html
<template name="Dep_Con">
<input disabled={{SBD_Dep_Con}} class="input" value="" type="text"/>
</template>
```

Js:

```js
Template.registerHelper("SBD_Dep_Con", function() {
    var returnval = "n";
    const ans = Session.get('chosen')
    const product = ProductList.findOne({ product: ans});
    console.log("product.dep_con:" + product.department_contact)
    if(product.department_contact == "N/A") {return true}
    else {return false}
});
```

I've successfully enable / disable an inputfield (text) in html depends on another dropbox's value using the code above.

The problem is when the inputfield is filled when enabled and followed by being disabled, the value filled remains.  Is there a way to reset an inputfield's value when its 'disabled' status change? Or am I looking at the wrong direction (i.e. there's a way for the form to not retrieve value from a disabled inputfield)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the input field before disabling it using jquery. I have modified your code slightly.

```
<template name="Dep_Con">
    <input disabled={{SBD_Dep_Con}} class="input" id="input_field" value="" type="text"/>
</template>
```

JS File

```
Template.registerHelper("SBD_Dep_Con", function() {
    var returnval = "n";
    const ans = Session.get('chosen');
    const product = ProductList.findOne({ product: ans});
    console.log("product.dep_con:" + product.department_contact)
    if(product.department_contact == "N/A") {
        $('#input_field').val('');   //Add this corresponding to id.
       return true   }
    else {
    return false}
});
```

Comment: that worked, thanks!  I had the same thing before and didn't work thinking it's not the way, only to realize i'm missing the '#'